# Can't connect to database inside local container

Tags: magento2, database

I have my magento installation and a mysql server running in two local containers and I can successfully connect to mysql from magento's container using `mysql -u root -p -h <mysql_container_ip>` but I get a `Port must be configured within host parameter` error when trying to access my site. Here's my env:

```php
'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '<mysql_container_ip>:3306',
                'dbname' => 'magento2',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '<password>',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I tried to execute `setup:upgrade` and it returned `Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

I folowed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to) and managed to make it work.